Arduino Nano ESP 32 board (ABX00083) SD library not working
I am working on a simple code to write data to a MicroSD card using Arduino nano ESP32 (ABX0083) and Df robot SPI MicroSD card module(DFR0229). I am not able to write to the SD card. I get the error condition "Error opening dta.txt for writing.".

All pins are connected correctly.  SD.h module is used. Pins are connected according to arduino nano-ESP pinout https://docs.arduino.cc/resources/pinouts/ABX00083-full-pinout.pdf

The default pinout used is"Arduino". The code works well with Arduino UNO. Following is the code.
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

// Define the chip select pin for the SD card module
const int chipSelect = 10;



void setup() {
  // Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
  //pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(chipSelect, OUTPUT);

  while (!Serial) {
    // Wait for the serial port to connect (needed for Leonardo and Micro)
  }

  Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");

  // Initialize the SD card
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Card failed, or not present");
    // Don't do anything more
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Card initialized.");

  // Open the existing file for writing
  File dataFile = SD.open("dta.txt", FILE_WRITE);

  // Check if the file opened successfully
  if (dataFile) {
    Serial.println("Writing to dta.txt...");

    // Write some example data
    dataFile.println("Appending new data");

    // Close the file
    dataFile.close();
    Serial.println("Data written to dta.txt successfully.");
  } else {
    // If the file didn't open, print an error
    Serial.println("Error opening dta.txt for writing.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Nothing to do here
}


At first make sure that the chip select (CS) pin is correctly defined and connected. The pin numbers might be different for the Arduino Nano ESP32.

The code work for Arduino Uno because it is the API for Arduino Uno's SD library. For Arduino Nano ESP32, it is an ESP32, so you should check the example for the ESP32 instead of the one for Uno. There are subtle differences, 1) unless you are going to reassign the SPI port, you don't need to pass-in the CS to SD.begin(); 2) For the ESP32 SD library, it is expecting a path instead of a filename when calling SD.open(), so it should be SD.open("/dta.txt", FILE_WRITE); instead of just dta.txt. See ESP32 SD library.

@hcheung turns out the problem was in declaring the file path.  It worked after putting "/ " as you suggested. Thanks.

The code work for Arduino Uno because it is the API for Arduino Uno's SD library. For Arduino Nano ESP32, it is an ESP32, so you should check the example for the ESP32 SD library instead of the one for Uno.
There are subtle differences:

unless you are going to re-assign the SPI port, you don't need to pass-in the CS to SD.begin();
Unlike the Arduino Uno SD library, which is expecting to pass in a filename, the ESP32 SD.open()is inherited from ESP32 FS library, which is expecting a path instead of a filename when calling SD.open(), so it should be SD.open("/dta.txt", FILE_WRITE); instead of just dta.txt.

